# iphone openGL ES 2 translating object

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, matrix, opengl-es-2.0

looking to move objects in scene with matrix translation, but can't get anything to stick. I can get the projection to move but i cant get the 2d square to move.

Render code in sprite class:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &self->_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);



glEnableVertexAttribArray(self.shader.positionSlot);
glVertexAttribPointer(self.shader.positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(self.shader.colorSlot);
glVertexAttribPointer(self.shader.colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid *)(sizeof(float) * 3));

GLuint indexBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices), Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

float matrix[16]; // trying to manipulate matrix here 
matrixSetIdentity(matrix);

float translateMatrix[16];
matrixSetTranslation(translateMatrix, 0, 0, 0);

float result[16];
matrixMultiply(matrix, translateMatrix, result);
glUniformMatrix4fv(self.shader.positionSlot, 1, 0, result); //this doesn't work, the object disappears?

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof(Vertices)/sizeof(Vertices[0]));
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(Indices)/sizeof(Indices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

heres the shader code:

```
attribute vec4 Position;
attribute vec4 SourceColor;

varying vec4 DestinationColor;
uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview;


 void main(void) {
 DestinationColor = SourceColor;
 gl_Position = Projection * Modelview * Position;
}
```

Now the frustrating part is that this works:

```
float h = 4.0f * self.frame.size.height / self.frame.size.width;
float projection[16];
[self.matrix projection:projection Left:-2 Right:2 Top:h/2 Bottom:-h/2 near:4 far:20];
glUniformMatrix4fv(self.shader.projectionUniform, 1, 0, projection);

float modelView[16];

matrixSetTranslation(modelView, 0.0, sin(CACurrentMediaTime()), -10.0);
glUniformMatrix4fv(self.shader.modelViewUniform, 1, 0, modelView);

glViewport(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
```

not sure why the top code doesn't seem to work but the bottom does. Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's very difficult to tell how much of the top code corresponds to the bottom code.

Comment: its sharing all the same functions for translation and identity, just the top is in a sprite class and the bottom is in the scene class. Let me know if there's anything that ya need to see?

Answer (score 0):

The projection matrix is being translated by a value which changes every frame (CACurrentMediaTime()). The model's transformation matrix is being translated by the same value.

That value is a translation of  0 x,0 y, and 0 z units (assuming that matrixSetTranslation behaves like GLKMatrixMakeTranslation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMatrix4/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation)), which is the identity matrix, multiplied by the identity matrix again. This give you the identity matrix, which is equivalent to multiplying a regular number by one.

Comment: as it sits now unfortunately it doesn't display while using the glUniformMatrix4fv. Its blank, no errors, nothing. I was using the 0,0,0 to see if it would render exactly where it was with out it. Could the glUniformMatrix4fv be conflicting with the attribute vec4 Position; tried changing the attribute to uniform and no render again.

Comment: That... is *not* the impression I got from the wording of your question. You said you couldn't get it to move," not "It doesn't appear at all." Are other things drawing correctly? Are you implying that it draws when you give it no data for the uniform at all? I think the real question then is what your matrixMultiply function does -- maybe it has a bug. Why aren't you using GLKit for matrix math?

Comment: Also, you should seriously consider refactoring your code -- if this stuff is happening in a rendering loop, it is hideously inefficient. The glDrawArrays and glDrawElements calls are redundant -- if you need indices, use glDrawElements, if you don't use glDrawArrays -- not both. You make a new VBO every cycle, and from the looks of things put the same data in. Do this once when you initialize your sprite class, and make it GL_STATIC_DRAW. You only need to enable a vertexAttribArray once. Are you trying to do something in 2D? If so, you probably don't need a projection matrix at all.

Comment: Hey I appriciate the feedback. Yea when i use glUnifromMatrix I can't see the quad with out it its perfect. I've been butchering the code to try to get the darn thing movin' so thats part of why it looks bad the other reason is that still new to opengl es so I'll definitely work on what you mentioned above. So other then the nasty code the gluniformMatrix should be working where it is? the functions being called are working correctly for the moving view, but not on the model.

Comment: Also I've worked with glkit in the past its great just wanna get a fuller knowledge of opengl es.

Comment: Then the problem most likely lies with how you are producing that matrix. Is the value of result actually the identity matrix when you pass it in? Try swapping in GLKit Math functions for your matrix math and see if it works. I think you misunderstand my comment about GLKit -- you can use the GLKit math utilities without using a GLKView or any of the other fixed-function type stuff. Unless you also want to implement all the math utilities yourself...

Comment: Yea was kinda hoping to learn the math side of it. Might be useful with writing for android even though I'm sure there's a GLKit equivalent over there.